# Estimation for the integral of square function from its integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued smooth function which has compactly supported Fourier transform and
$$2\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx \leq 2+ c, $$ for some sufficiently small $c>0$ with
$\chi_{[-1,1]}(s) \leq f(s)$ for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, can we find any bounds (upper and lower bounds) of the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)^{2} dx $$ from the above condition?

Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well since $f\geqslant \chi_{[-1,1]}$, you immediately get $\int_{\mathbb R} f^2\, dx \geqslant 2$. Would that be enough for the lower bound?

Comment: Yes. In fact, what I mainly wanted is the upper bound.